# How to parallelize this code using async await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, binance

I am trying to understand async programming better. I wrote this code and added async but the speed is still the same. Each subscription call takes more than a second so when I print it in the console, it's still working synchronously.

All I want is to perform each subscribe call asynchronously. Also because the first function has many subscribe calls, I am not sure whether that should be async or whether I should async the second call. Because at the start of the program, I have to call the first function like 50 times. Later on I only call the first function 1 time when a new item is added.

```
public static List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> AddNewSubscription(
    BinanceSocketClient socketClient, Coin coin)
{
    List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> tasks =
        new List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>();
    List<UpdateSubscription> subs = new List<UpdateSubscription>();

    var sub = socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToSymbolTickerUpdatesAsync(coin.SymbolPair,
        data =>
    {
        coin.Price = data.LastPrice;
        coin.LowestDailyPrice = data.LowPrice;
        coin.HighestDailyPrice = data.HighPrice;
        coin.PriceChangeInPercentDaily = data.PriceChangePercent;
    });
    tasks.Add(sub);
    subs.Add(sub.Result.Data);

    sub = socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToKlineUpdatesAsync(coin.SymbolPair,
        KlineInterval.OneHour, data =>
    {
        coin.LastHourOpenPrice = data.Data.Open;
        coin.LastHourVolume = data.Data.BaseVolume;
        coin.TotalBuyVolume = data.Data.TakerBuyBaseVolume;
        coin.TotalSellVolume = coin.LastHourVolume - coin.TotalBuyVolume;
    });
    tasks.Add(sub);
    subs.Add(sub.Result.Data);

    sub = socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToKlineUpdatesAsync(coin.SymbolPair,
        KlineInterval.OneMinute, data =>
    {
        coin.LastMinuteOpenPrice = data.Data.Open;
    });
    tasks.Add(sub);
    subs.Add(sub.Result.Data);

    Utility.ActiveSubscriptions.Add(coin.Symbol, subs);

    return tasks;
}

public static async Task AddNewSubscriptions(BinanceSocketClient socketClient,
    IEnumerable<Coin> coins)
{
    List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> tasks =
        new List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>();
    int index = 0;

    foreach (var coin in coins)
    {
        var subs = Utility.AddNewSubscription(socketClient, coin);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1} : {2}", index, coins.Count(), coin.Symbol);
        ++index;

        tasks.Union(subs);
    }

    //foreach(var task in tasks)
    //  Utility.ActiveSubscriptions.Add ( coin.Symbol, task.Result.Data );

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}




public async static Task<List<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> AddNewSubscription ( BinanceSocketClient socketClient, IEnumerable<Coin> coins )
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> ( );
    var taskdict = new Dictionary<string, List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>> ( );

    foreach ( var coin in coins )
    {
        var subtasks = Utility.CreateSubscriptionTasks ( socketClient, coin );
        tasks.AddRange ( subtasks );

        taskdict.Add ( coin.Symbol, subtasks );
    }

    await Task.WhenAll ( tasks );

    foreach ( var task in taskdict )
    {
        var subs = task.Value.Select ( x => x.Result.Data ).ToList ( );
        Utility.ActiveSubscriptions.Add ( task.Key, subs );
    }

    return tasks.Select ( x => x.Result ).ToList ( );
}
```

Comment: You I should make more liberal use of `var` btw, especially on lines like `x = new List<X<Y>>`

Comment: async will not speed up your application. It will provide you better throughput by better resource utilization.

Comment: Without having any idea about Binance, is it possible that your app is throttled by the remote server? They may not allow multiple concurrent connections from the same client.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: No it's not that, it's just that if I wait for the subscription to finish it takes a lot o time for 50 plus coins. I need it this way so when I remove a coin, I can unsub, rather than unsub everything then it takes about 20 seconds to update the subs again, and the other coins lose the price connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `.Result` unless you want to block the thread and wait for the result. In this case you probably don't want to wait for the result until the very end, after all the tasks have been started.

```
public static List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> AddNewSubscription ( BinanceSocketClient socketClient, Coin coin )
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> ( );

    var sub = socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToSymbolTickerUpdatesAsync ( coin.SymbolPair, data =>
    {
        coin.Price = data.LastPrice;
        coin.LowestDailyPrice = data.LowPrice;
        coin.HighestDailyPrice = data.HighPrice;
        coin.PriceChangeInPercentDaily = data.PriceChangePercent;
    } );
    tasks.Add ( sub );

    sub = socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToKlineUpdatesAsync ( coin.SymbolPair, KlineInterval.OneHour, data =>
    {
        coin.LastHourOpenPrice = data.Data.Open;
        coin.LastHourVolume = data.Data.BaseVolume;
        coin.TotalBuyVolume = data.Data.TakerBuyBaseVolume;
        coin.TotalSellVolume = coin.LastHourVolume - coin.TotalBuyVolume;
    } );
    tasks.Add ( sub );

    sub = socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToKlineUpdatesAsync ( coin.SymbolPair, KlineInterval.OneMinute, data =>
    {
        coin.LastMinuteOpenPrice = data.Data.Open;
    } );
    tasks.Add ( sub );

    //Here is where we wait for them all to complete in parallel
    Task.WaitAll( tasks );
    var subs = tasks.Select( x => x.Result.Data ).ToList(); 

    Utility.ActiveSubscriptions.Add ( coin.Symbol, subs );

    return tasks;
}
```

Comment: The method shouldn’t return a List<Task<CallResult<…>> if it synchronously ends, but just a List<CallResult<…>>. However a much better approach would be to declare the method async, use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` instead of the WaitAll and return Task<List<CallResult<…>>>.

Comment: @ckuri, can you please post a simple example?

Comment: @John: It gives this error: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<CryptoExchange.Net.Objects.CallResult<CryptoExchange.Net.Sockets.UpdateSubscription>>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'  367 Active
"

Comment: Also when I change the return type I get: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1983 The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, or IAsyncEnumerator<T> 323 Active
"

Comment: @JoanVenge Change John’s first line to `public static async Task<List<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> AddNewSubscription ( BinanceSocketClient socketClient, Coin coin )`, replace `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` with `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`, and instead of `return tasks` do `return tasks.Select(x => x.Result).ToList()`. As AddNewSubscription is now also fully async, you also should call it with `await AddNewSubscription(…)`, because if you use async you should use it all the way to the top.

Comment: @ckuri, it works! Without using await in the call, it didnt work.

Comment: @ckuri, only thing I am wondering is if this is the best way. For example I have about 5 calls to that subscribe function in the first function which are now executing in parallel, right? But now I am looping over a list to call this function. Am I better of gathering all these tasks rather than awaiting them 5 by 5?

Comment: @ckuri: I added the code that's calling the same function over a collection, when I do this, it doesn't work. Manually awaiting in the loop works, so not sure why this doesn't because I am gathering all the tasks the same way. Am I missing something? Also why do I have to return tasks in the end?

Comment: @JoanVenge If you call AddNewSubscription 5 times (and these call the inner method AddNewSubscriptions n-times), put it in a list, and call Task.WhenAll on it, then the inner 5xn tasks will run in parallel. It doesn’t really hurt that that you have nested Task.WhenAlls. For async you always need to a return a Task, that must be awaited for it to work.

Comment: @ckuri, I was thinking when I await them 5 by 5, i wasn't able to launch them say over high core count like 64 cores effectively. That's why I was trying to gather all tasks beforehand for a collection that I know will all call the same function.